# MVC Routing issue with same parameter different names

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I have the following routings in my RoutingConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Not working why?
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AdminLoginRequestUrl",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{requestUrl}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", requestUrl= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The problem is that the second routing is not working
What do i miss here? does someone has any tips or Ideas MVC is abit new for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create different route only by differentiating parameter name, both route present similar one. Also move your custom route above default one. You can try this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AdminLoginRequestUrl",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/route2/{requestUrl}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", requestUrl= UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

you can use anything insted of `route2` to differentiate from default route

Comment: What has route2 has to be ? sorry i'm new to MVC

Comment: anything you want to use to differentiate from the default one

Comment: just need to make some difference between them

Comment: What if i already have 2 params than i need to add a thirth>>

Comment: no its not param it will be part of the route like admin/login/route2/{yourparam}

Comment: Do i need to declare route2 in my controller somewhere ?

Comment: no in if you have 2 param then its already different than the default

Comment: no you don't need to declear anything to use route2 its just a string content in route

Answer (score 0):

You cannot differ your routs by variable names. You can create more specific route like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AdminLoginRequestUrl",
        url: "Admin/{action}/{requestUrl}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", requestUrl= UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Note that the order of registration is significant.

Or you can rename your parameters to something that will be appropriate for both controllers and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`, you can read about it here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/[1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).

**Edit:** Changed link for better article.

Then you can use attributes to define more specific rules on your actions.

Example:

```
public class Admin : Controller
{
    [Route("admin/{requestUrl}")]
    public ActionResult Login(string requestUrl) { ... }
}
```